# How to prevent white text from CSS file from appearing in rendered React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render a button in React that changes text and color when you click on it.

I got it to work, but whenever I render the app, the title from the head of the `index.html` file and the text from the `App.module.css` file appear on the page (in white text). I have searched for a solution, but I cannot seem to find one.

**Btn.js**

```
import styles from './App.module.css';

const Btn = ({toggleIt, toggle}) => {
  return(
    <>
     <button onClick={toggleIt} className={toggle ? styles.btntrue : styles.btnfalse}>
        {toggle ? "true" : "false"}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Btn;
```

**App.module.css**

```
* {
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btntrue {
  background-color: green
  ;
}

.btnfalse {
  background-color: red
  ;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import Btn from "./btn"


function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

  const toggleIt = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle)
  }


  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Btn
      toggleIt = {toggleIt}
      toggle = {toggle}
    />
  </React.Fragment>

  );
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js (for completeness sake)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Button</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

How can I remove this text from the screen or is it always there and you have to style around it?

[Error message one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uF3b.png)

[Error message two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Cky.png)

Comment: Sounds like a bundler issue. How are you bundling your project?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. I run it using `npm run start` and I am using Atom. If that doesn't answer your question how would I find out how I am bundling the project?

Comment: How did you set up this project?

Comment: I used `npx create-react-app` and removed all the files in the `public` and `src` folders except for the ones listed above.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file is declaring *all elements to be visible* with white text, including normally-invisible ones like `<style>` or `<title>`:

```css
* { /* Make ALL elements... */
  display: flex; /* ...displayed visibly, with "flex" display type... */
  color: white; /* ...and white text */
}
```

Normally, things like `<style>` have `display: none` by default to make them hidden, but here you explicitely overwrite it by `display: flex`.

You should instead apply these styles only to the elements that need it, instead of `*` (all elements). Look into [scoped CSS in React](https://medium.com/@cosmvs/scoping-css-classes-to-a-component-in-reactjs-using-css-modules-c294dc6a0e02) to see how to apply CSS rules only to elements inside a certain component.

The issue with your existing approach was that CSS scoping in React works mainly by appending unique suffixes to class names (so your `btntrue` class may become `btntrue_a732uw` or something like that, making sure that no two `btntrue` class names of different components will clash), however if you *don't* use a class name for a rule (such as you do with `*`), it also can't be scoped! You can avoid that by using `.allflex *` for example, instead of just `*`, and then applying the `allflex` class name to your component's root element.